# Show Facebook Comment Count In Blog (Not Wordpress)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-comments

I'm planning on using facebook comments plugin for my new blog website and would like to show some stats in the article header (Date, Views, Times Commented, etc) but I can't get the facebook view count to show up.  Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=277028005786031&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

At display position

```
<b>Commented On:</b> <fb:comments-count href="http://example.com/"></fb:comments-count> Times
```

All this shows on the page is:

**Commented On:** Times

How can I get it to display the actual number of posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of API `2.0` each API request requires a valid `access_token` and from your code I see that you are using `2.0`, This means sending sensitive data to the Graph which is not safe at all, if you're using `JS`

A valid `access_token`

- App `access_token`, combination of in app id & secret in this form `{app_id}|{app_secret}` (recommended because it doesn't expire)
- a user `access_token`, issued by authorizing an app (expires after 2 hour of issuing, 60 days after extending)

### Solution #1 (easy)

Switch back to API v1.0, **available until **April 30th, 2015**

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId={app_id}&version=v1.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

### Solution #2 (advance)

You tagged `PHP`, so the solution i will post is for future use,

**`comments-count.php`**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$config = array('appId'  => '{Your-app-Id}',
                'secret' => '{Your-app-secret}');

/** If the $_GET['href'] is set and not empty **/
if( isset($_GET['href']) && !empty($_GET['href']) ) {

    $href = $_GET['href']; 
    $commentsCount = getCommentsCount($href);

    // check if the HREF has comments count
    if ( array_key_exists('comments', $commentsCount) ) {
        $comments = $commentsCount['comments'];
    } else {
        $comments = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode( array('meta'     => array('code' => 200),
                            'id'       => $commentsCount['id'],
                            'comments' => $comments,
                            'shares'   => $commentsCount['shares']), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

} else {

    /** else print the error below (JOSN encoded) **/
    header('HTTP/1.1 400');
    echo json_encode( array('meta'          => array('code' => 400),
                            'message' => 'href is not provided'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT requires PHP 5.4 or higher, you should remove it if you have 5.3 or lower
}

function getCommentsCount($href) {
    global $config;
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?id='. $href . '&access_token=' . $config['appId'] . '|' . $config['secret']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $r  = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode($r, true);
}
```

**`comments-count.js`**

```
;(function($) {

    $.fn.facebookCommentsCount = function( options ) {

            var $target = this;

            /** Plugin default settings **/
            var settings = $.extend({

                    apiPath          : 'fb-comments-count/comments-count.php', // Path to `comments-count.php`
                    zeroComments     : null,
                    oneComment       : null,
                    multipleComments : null

            }, options);


            return $target.each( function() {

                var href = $(this).attr('data-href');
                var $this = $(this)

                $.ajax({
                    url:  settings.apiPath,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { href : href },
                    success: function(data) {

                        if (data.comments === 0) {

                            if(settings.zeroComments) {
                                $this.html(data.comments + '&nbsp;' + settings.zeroComments);
                            } eles {
                                $this.html(data.comments);
                            }

                        } else if (data.comments === 1 ) {

                            if(settings.oneComment) {
                                $this.html( data.comments + '&nbsp;' + settings.oneComment);
                            } else {
                                $this.html(data.comments);
                            }

                        } else {

                            if(settings.multipleComments) {
                                $this.html( data.comments + '&nbsp;' + settings.multipleComments);
                            } else {
                                $this.html(data.comments);
                            }

                        }

                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                      console.log(error);
                    }
                });

            });

    };

}(jQuery));
```

#### How-To Use

In your page add `div`, `span` or `p` (inline elements are better, `div` is block)

```
<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="{URL}">0</dvi>

<script>
$('.fb-comments-count').facebookCommentsCount();
</script>
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/adamazad/facebook-comments-count)

[Demo](http://hub.aada.me/facebook-comments-count/)

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm all for using easy solutions so reverting back to v1.0 is fine for me for a year - The second solution seems like a lot of code just to pull out a few numbers so I probably won't upgrade to 2.0. Thanks again